# NVMe SSD on Azure

Tags: azure, cloud, storage, azure-storage

I am trying to find equivalent of an i3.4xlarge AWS ec2 instance on Azure. I am not sure if Microsoft Azure VMs have NVMe drives.

Does Azure have NVMe based VMs?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has announced NVMe storage is now available.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-storage

> The Lsv2-series features high throughput, low latency, directly mapped local NVMe storage running on the AMD EPYCTM 7551 processor with an all core boost of 2.55GHz and a max boost of 3.0GHz. The Lsv2-series VMs come in sizes from 8 to 80 vCPU in a simultaneous multi-threading configuration. There is 8 GiB of memory per vCPU, and one 1.92TB NVMe SSD M.2 device per 8 vCPUs, with up to 19.2TB (10x1.92TB) available on the L80s v2.

Specifically for your question an AWS i3.4xlarge has 16 vCPUs, 122 GiB memory, and 2 x 1.9 TB NVMe while the generally equivalent Azure Standard_L16s_v2 has 16 vCPU, 128 GiB memory, and 2 x 1.92 TB NVMe.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no.

The closest match on Azure is the [L-Series VMs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-storage-optimized-virtual-machines-l-series/) although it does not seem to have NVMe and uses the '[Premium Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/premium-storage-performance)'

Answer (score 1):

The Lsv2-series features high throughput, low latency, directly mapped local NVMe storage running on the AMD EPYC ™ 7551 processor with an all core boost of 2.55GHz and a max boost of 3.0GHz. The Lsv2-series VMs come in sizes from 8 to 80 vCPU in a simultaneous multi-threading configuration. There is 8 GiB of memory per vCPU, and one 1.92TB NVMe SSD M.2 device per 8 vCPUs, with up to 19.2TB (10x1.92TB) available on the L80s v2.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-storage

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that the NVMe disks provided with the Lsv2-series are **ephemeral** so you'll lose everything if you need to stop/deallocate the VM for whatever reasons:

[*<sup>2</sup> Local NVMe disks are ephemeral, data will be lost on these disks if you stop/deallocate your VM.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/lsv2-series)

I've learned it the hard way recently, I had to stop the VM to resize the main OS disk (as Azure doesn't support online resizing) and after the operation my whole database was gone!